# Как упростить добавление новых правил для Valitron или помощь с ООП от знающих?

Tags: php

Есть такой симпатичный валидатор - Valitron, добавление новых правил в нем реализуется вот как:

```
Valitron\Validator::addRule('alwaysFail', function($field, $value, array $params, array $fields) {
        return false;
    }, 'Everything you do is wrong. You fail.');
```

Я не хочу засорять структуру приложения вот такими обрывками кода и хочу написать механизм, который будет перебирать набор правил из определенной папки и добавлять правила, как-то так:

```
class UniqueRule {
    public $name;
    public $message;

    public function __construct($name, $message) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function handler(function($field, $value, array $params, array $fields) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

И в цикле цеплять эти файлики, брать нейм в качества имени правила, мессейдж как сообщение об ошибке и саму функцию брать из handler.
Но, конкретно как я написал - это с точки зрения ООП че-то не то. Тут явно надо как-то передавать функцию как замыкание, а здесь передача пойдет как вызов. Мне явно не хватает знаний об ООП, чтобы осилить правильную реализацию. Сообщество - помоги! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно создать интерфейс который будет имплементировать каждый класс-правило.

**Interfaces\RuleInterface**

```php
namespace Interfaces;

interface RuleInterface
{
    public function getMessage(): string;

    public function getName(): string;

    public function handler($field, $value, array $params, array $fields): bool;
}
```

Далее нужно создать само правило, имплементировать *RuleInterface*, реализовать методы.

**Rules\UniqueRule**

```php
namespace Rules;

use Interfaces\RuleInterface;

class UniqueRule implements RuleInterface
{
    public function getMessage(): string
    {
        return 'Error! Is not unique';
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'unique';
    }

    public function handler($field, $value, array $params, array $fields): bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Я бы создал отдельный файл который бы хранил массив с правилами в папке *config* например, но это уже на собственное усмотрение. Сканировать папку и подгружать классы как по мне не самая лучшая затея. Например:

**config/rules.php**

```php
return [
    \Rules\UniqueRule::class,
    \Rules\MaxRule::class,
    \Rules\MinRule::class,
    // .....
];
```

Ну и наконец подгрузка самих правил, в удобном для вас месте.

```php
$rules = include __DIR__ . '/config/rules.php';

foreach ($rules as $ruleClass){
    // создаем объект класса-правила
    $rule = new $ruleClass();

    // если правило не имплементирует нужный интерфей то бросаем исключение
    if (!($rule instanceof \Interfaces\RuleInterface))
        throw new Exception('Rule must implement RuleInterface');

    // расширяем базовый валидатор
    Valitron\Validator::addRule($rule->getName(), function($field, $value, array $params, array $fields) use($rule) {
        // вызываем метод handler и возвращаем результат его работы
        return $rule->handler($field, $value, $params, $fields);
    }, $rule->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Браво! Вы отлично помогли! Как минимум, я стал чууууточку лучше разбираться в ООП)))